# Dell XPS 13 9310 overheating

Tags: dell, 21.10, overheating, xps

After 1 year os usage, it started overheating. Yes I'm a heavy user but it didn't do this before. Could this be related to the new ubuntu I installed? I'm on 21.10

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +83.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +78.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +82.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +79.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +83.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

these very easily to do 95 degrees and one every 2 days it gets too hot and it shuts down itself for protection. There's nothing blocking the fan output.

My 2 fans are working:

```
dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
fan1:        7504 RPM
fan2:        7188 RPM
```

Is there a way to make the fans run faster, or something else I can do? I run a VM and heavy stuff inside the VM but I did more heavy stuff before and nothing happened. Now even the latex stuff in the bottom peeled off.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu were you using before that didn’t have the heat issue? If it was 20.04, did you use the Hardware Enablement kernel? I find the HWE lines to be much better for thermal management than interim releases 

Comment: How's your fan? Is it blocked? How dusty is the inside of your computer?

Comment: what is your processor make and model. Have your tried thermald, with a lower trip  point temperature?